# ExtJS cross domain issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, cross-domain

I'm new to extjs and i'm facing problem with crossdomain issue.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    method: "POST",
 url:'url',
    params:{
        ahq_id: '104',
        username:'',
        password:'',
        callback:'WCL_Parser',
    },
    async: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response){
    console.info(response);

    }
});
```

I'm getting error as

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://182.73.236.115:8080/WCLRESTService/rest/Map/showVehiclesOnMap. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8282' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Even i tried with callback function also

```
    function WCL_Parser(data){
    console.info(data);
}
```

The error is not resolved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to get a JSONP answer, but using an Ajax request. Where on earth did you find `dataType: 'jsonp'`; it isn't in the ExtJS docs. Use a JsonP store and be done with it.

Comment: can you help me in this with any example